# Django how to save logs in transaction.atomic()

Tags: django

Suppose you are processing order when payment is confirmed.

```
with transaction.atomic(): 

   do something like subtract stock
   log stuff in DB so that we can later investigate what went wrong 
   if something goes wrong: # this line of code may reside in a function nested deep 
     raise
   do more to finalize the order
```

When there's an exception, db rolls back fine, but I want the logging to be persisted in the db.

I'm thinking creating a celery task and do the logging the background, (not sure if it's going to work).

Are there better alternatives?

Comment: Are you able to write the log first before the "do something" block? You could log first and then enter the atomic block to do the work you want to roll back in the case of an error.

Comment: You can commit manually. When the exception will happen rollback transaction and commit only logs to database https://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.5.x/topics/db/transactions.html#django.db.transaction.commit_manually

Comment: The db isn't ideal for logging, for specifically this reason. Use a normal log file, which can be streamed into something like Kibana.

Answer (score 0):

As i can understand your problem, this may help you:-

```
try:
   with transaction.atomic():
      do something like subtract stock
except:
   log staff into db to investigate what went wrong 
do more to finalize the order
```